# Ajax sempre cai em 'error' mesmo quando em sucesso (C# MVC5)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Vamos lá. Tenho o seguinte método:

**C#**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult PostOnCRM(string textBoxFirstName, string textBoxCountry, string textBoxLastName, string textBoxEmail, string textBoxTitle, string textBoxTelephone, string textBoxCompany, string textBoxWebsite, string textAreaNote, string checkBoxUpdates)
    {
        try
        {
            bool isValidEmail = Regex.IsMatch(textBoxEmail,
            @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
            @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));

            if (!isValidEmail)
                throw new Exception("E-mail is not a valid one");
            LeadInformation lead = new LeadInformation()
            {
                Subject = "Web site",
                FirstName = textBoxFirstName,
                LastName = textBoxLastName,
                JobTitle = textBoxTitle,
                Address1_Country = textBoxCountry,
                EmailAddress1 = textBoxEmail,
                MobilePhone = textBoxTelephone,
                WebsiteUrl = textBoxWebsite,
                Description = textAreaNote,
                DoNotEmail = checkBoxUpdates.Contains("Yes") ? true : false
            };
 //Aqui existe um método de insert que funciona corretamente

            return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Your message successfuly sent!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, responseText = e.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

E faço uma chamada ajax para ele:

**Ajax**

```
$("#formContact").submit(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var formdata = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        url: 'http://localhost:59289/Lead/PostOnCRM',
        data: formdata,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert('Error - ' + response.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

O método executa perfeitamente. Faz o insert no banco mas quando retorna para o método ajax ele sempre cai no 'error' e não envia nem o response que eu enviei. O que pode ser?

Já peço perdão por pegar os parâmetros dessa forma (principalmente o lance do bool) e por não usar um Bind ou qualquer coisa, mas isso não é relevante para a pergunta

Comment: Uma descrição do erro encontrado poderia ser útil. Acha que pode adicionar o log do console ao corpo da pergunta?

Comment: Não tem erro nenhum. '. Gostaria de poder ajudar com mais detalhes mas não tem nada. Ele simplesmente executa perfeitamente no C# mas quando volta ele apenas volta pro js direto no 'error' sempre, indepententemente do que eu mandei de return na função.

Comment: No módulo de ferramentas do desenvolvedor do seu browser aparece o quê quando a chamada é realizada?

Comment: Eu não tenho muita certeza, mas, sabe esse trecho de código: `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` deveria ser `JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet`, porque o método é decorado com `POST`, faz um teste e depois deixe um mensagem

Comment: não aparece nenhum erro e a response não é a passada pelo meu método e sim um outro que possui abort length = 1.
Ajuda? Eu tirei um print mas não dá pra enviar aqui, né? :p

Comment: Segue a imagem https://postimg.org/image/e86q3hcol/

Comment: não é o caso de usar "JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet"

Comment: A melhor forma de saber o que está ocorrendo é fazer uma chamada pelo fiddler e ver o resultado, já que sua chamada está ok. Uma observação, eu tenho uma aplicação que uso muito o ajax mas só com HTTPPOST e acabei de conferir e não uso nenhum retorno com JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet. Outro detalhe é que uso em todas as chamadas asyncrona, segue exemplo: public async Task<JsonResult> BuscaProdutos(). Já que o ajax como default já é async.

Answer (score 1):

Isso dai acontece porque você está capturando a exception e dando um return Json().

Quando você usa o return Json() o http response é colocado com Status Code 20x (sucesso). Não é porque no seu json você está colocando success = true/false que o Status Code vai mudar.

Pra entrar no callback de error do ajax vocë tem que deixar estourar a exception.

Comment: na verdade ele sempre me retorna erro mas isso que você falou eu não sabia. vou mudar isso quando chegar no trabalho amanhã :D

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta retornar somente success. Pelo menos com Angular e o MVC5 caia sempre no erro quando passava qualquer resultado além de OK.

Outra solução é tentar por o Response em 200 na mão.

```
Response.StatusCode = 200
```